# Looking a data structure that is a Map but in which keys can be values, values can be keys

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

A **Map** maps from keys to values and provides quick access based on the knowledge of the key.

Does there exist a data structure like Maps which supports both key to value and value to key access? Sometimes I may want to derefence the Map via the value, while other times by the key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in the JDK, but you can find a good BiMap implementation in the Google Collections : http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/index.html) provides a [BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/package-use.html#org.apache.commons.collections.bidimap) which serves this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [org.apache.commons.collections.BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html).

> Defines a map that allows bidirectional lookup between key and values.